# Missing RabbitVCS icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, context-menu, rabbitvcs

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 last summer. From this time on I did not have context menu items for RabbitVCS anymore. All the menu items are still there - but no icons. Is there any solution for this? Of course, I enabled "menus have icons" and stuff...

Comment: FYI: TortoiseHG-Nautilus is also affected on 18.04 LTS. Seems to be a bug in modern Nautilus.